# How do I find what content is supplying my current page?

Tags: nodes

I have a webpage on my site that doesn't have edit tabs, so I am not sure where this website is retrieving content. How can I find out what content represents this webpage? I am using Drupal 7.

Comment: Check page path in views and panels, may be the page is coming from there.

Comment: grep the site files for the page's path.

Comment: Inspecting CSS classes on the body and content wrappers often help to identify what module produced it (unless it's custom, then it's up to whoever developed it to add those classes)

Answer (score 0):

Take a look if you can see the contextual "settings wheel" in the top right corner.
This can provide you with a direct link to edit the "page"/"view" or Panel that you are on

[image: Contextual Wheel]